# Android Hilt Problem [Hilt] Could not get element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

when i run my app i get this error:

error: [Hilt] Could not get element for m.yaz.agh.pos.di.AppModule: java.lang.NullPointerException: Could not get element for m.yaz.agh.pos.di.AppModule
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:994)
at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsMetadata.getDependency(AggregatedDepsMetadata.java:195)

this is AppModule Code:

```
package m.yaz.agh.pos.di

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import m.yaz.agh.pos.data.db.PosDatabase
import m.yaz.agh.pos.data.db.TransactionDao
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePosDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context, PosDatabase::class.java, PosDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
    ).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTransactionDao(database: PosDatabase): TransactionDao =
        database.transactionDao()


}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add the AppModule code?